# react firebase firestore empty useEffect useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

having an issue, when the when nav to the comp the items state is empty, if I edit the code and page refreshes its shows up and if I add the state to the useEffect "[itemCollectionRef, items]" it's an inf loop but the data is their anyone have a better idea or way to fetch the data for display from firestore.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Grid, Box, Button, Space } from "@mantine/core";
import { ItemBadge } from "../../components/NFAItemBadge";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { db, auth } from "../../firebase";
import { getFirestore, query, getDocs, collection, where, addDoc } from "firebase/firestore";
import { useAuthState } from "react-firebase-hooks/auth";


const ItemTrack = () => {
  const [user, loading, error] = useAuthState(auth);
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const itemCollectionRef = collection(db, "items");

  useEffect(() => {
    //if(!user) return navigate('/');
    //if(loading) return;
    const q = query(itemCollectionRef, where("uid", "==", user.uid));
    const getItems = async () => {
      const data = await getDocs(q);
      setItems(data.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })));
      console.log("Fetched Items: ", items);
    };
    getItems();
  }, []);

  if (loading) {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Initialising User....</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
  if (error) {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Error: {error}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
  if (user) {
    return (
      <Box sx={{ maxWidth: 1000 }} mx="auto">
      </Box>
    );
  } else {
    return navigate("/");
  }
};

export default ItemTrack;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will depend how you will render the data from the `useEffect`. `setState` does not make changes directly to the state object. It just creates queues for React core to update the state object of a React component. If you add the state to the useEffect, it compares the two objects, and since they have a different reference, it once again fetches the items and sets the new items object to the state. The state updates then triggers a re-render in the component. And on, and on, and on...

As I stated above, it will depend on how you want to show your data. If you just want to log your data into your console then you must use a temporary variable rather than using setState:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const newItems = data.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id }))
  console.log(newItems)
  // setItems(newItems)
}, [])
```

You could also use multiple useEffect to get the updated state object:

```
useEffect(() => {
  setItems(data.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id }))) 
}, [])
useEffect(() => { console.log(items) }, [items])
```

If you now want to render it to the component then you have to call the state in the component and map the data into it. Take a look at the sample code below:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const q = query(itemCollectionRef, where("uid", "==", user.uid));
  const getItems = async () => {
    const data = await getDocs(q);
    setItems(data.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })));
  };
  getItems();
}, []);

return (
  <div>
    <p>SomeData: <p/>
    {items.map((item) => (
      <p key={item.id}>{item.fieldname}</p>
    ))}
  </div>
);
```

Comment: thank you appreciate the help and information that was extremly helpful!