# Issue rendering data from firestore document in react native

Tags: react-native, asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore, mapping, rendering

I created a map for the array of `exercises` in my database, and then for each `exercise`, which is a document reference, I'm getting the data from that document reference and setting it to a state. This is resulting in an infinite loop right now.

If I remove the `setExerciseData` line, the console logs the exercise object's data that I'm expecting to see. I'm really not sure what the correct way to render the name field from this data is.

```
{workout.exercises.map((exercise) => {
    async function getData(exercise) {
      getDoc(exercise).then((doc) => {
        console.log(doc.data());
        setExerciseData(doc.data());
      });
    }

    getData(exercise);

    return (
       <Text>{exerciseData.name}</Text>
    )
})}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `useEffect()`?

Comment: Hi @kobo , have you checked my posted answer? Let me know if you have any questions or clarifications. Also, See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `useEffect()` and `setState()` to be able to render your data. Also, Firebase Firestore is Asynchronous in nature, as a general note, no one should be trying to convert an Async operation into a sync operation as this will cause problems. You need to use an Asynchronous function to fetch data from Firestore. See sample code below:

```
const getExerciseData = async () => {
    const docRef = doc(db, "<collection-name>", '<document-id>')
    const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef)

    if (docSnap.exists()) {
      // console.log("Document data:", docSnap.data())
      setExerciseData(docSnap.data())
    } else {
      // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
      console.log("No such document!")
    }
}

useEffect(() => {
    getExerciseData()
}, [])

return (
    <Text>{exerciseData.name}</Text>
)
```

You could also check my answer on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72993899/16895640) for more use-cases.